# JQuery force plain text on variable inside append

Tags: jquery

I have something similar to this function, where `task` is an object containing a few user-defined attributes:

```
function addTask(list, task) {
    list.append('<li class="task-item">' + task.name + '<span>Some Other</span></li>');
}
```

The problem here, of course, is that values might include HTML, and the browser will render it as such. Is it possible to force `task.name` to be parsed as plain text inside the append?

Note: See one of my solutions in the answers below.

**EDIT**: Added some relevant HTML I have inside the `<li>`. See my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

```
function addTask(list, task) {
    list.append('<li class="task-item"></li>'); // dont include the text or inner html yet
}

$el = $('li:last-child', list); 
$el.text(task.name); // force plain text
$el.append('<span>Some Other</span>');
```

This solves the `text()` method from overwriting my inner html content. It works. Still open to other ideas though.

Comment: `list.append('...').find('li').last().append(document.createTextNode(task.name));` seems plain JS is better in place here.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid so many statements for each line, but it appears to be the cleanest, most readable way. Your method is quite hairy :)

Comment: No man, you gotta chain if you can. You could put the methods on a new line though for overview. ;-)

Comment: Shame on my old self. Anyone reading this now, please adhere to @Shikkediel's suggestion to chain. It's the right thing to do! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Replace less-than signs (<) with the HTML entity `&lt;`:

```js
function addTask(list, task) {
  list.append('<li class="task-item">' + task.name.replace(/</g,'&lt;') +
              '<span>Some Other</span></li>'
             );
}

addTask($('ul'),{name: '<a>This is a task</a> '});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

**[Updated]**: Try the code that follows:

```
function addTask(list, task) {
    list.append('<li class="task-item"><pre>' + task.name + '</pre></li>');
}
```

Comment: As part of the design, I actually want it to keep any html tags, I just don't want it to render AS html. So, if they name a task  "<a>some title</a>", the title will show in plain text as exactly that. The text() method works, but it overwrites my inner html, thus the problem.

Comment: surround the `task.name` with `<pre>`. I have updated my solution.

Comment: `<pre>` doesn't quite do what I need. That's used for preformatted text. HTML tags can still be rendered as HTML inside it.